# How to speed up an sql query

Tags: sql, performance

I have a table which lists advertising actions by brands. Each action is recorded by one entry as shown in the excel file which you can see in the drive folder below. There are about 7mil records in the table. 
I am running several queries which run fine but i am facing an issue with one specific report. This report lists and ranks the clients (Column L in Excel file) by total amounts spent on advertising. This report takes about a minute to generate if the date range set is anywhere from two months to two years.

Below is a copy of the query

```
select customer_id, sum(value) as value 
from `data` 
where ((`date` >= '2019-01-01' and `date` <= '2019-12-31')) 
group by `customer_id` 
order by `value` desc, `customer_id` asc;
```

This report takes about a minute to generate if the date range set is anywhere from 2 months to two years. If my date range selection is for one month or less, it takes less than 3 seconds.

I need to get this query to process in less than 10-15 seconds max. We tried to come up with ideas such as creating a new table in the DB especially for this query but it hit a wall when we saw that we still had to keep all date records, and we could therefore not group the results in the table.

We really are open to any kind of idea that would make this query faster, including DB changes.

Below is the link to the folder which contains a copy of the DB structure and a sample data set exported from the data table which contains all the data.

[Drive Folder](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkLQNUJq2m_dgTGQME49NZZnj7Bn?e=vS9dSj)

Comment: This query on 7 million records should not be taking a minute -- unless you have really slow hardware or really big records.

Comment: It does not say what SQL you are running but i had similar problems with my MySql database until i added indexes (it was poorly configured to begin with)

Comment: Actually we tried running the query on several machines but the result was always the same. So we concluded it was not hardware issue. I am not sure by what your unit of big is. You can look at the actual record in the sample data set in the link below.

Answer (score 1):

You should make an index on fields that are essential to the criteria of your query. In this case something like:

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_data_date` ON `data`(`date`);
CREATE INDEX `idx_data_customer_id` ON `data`(`customer_id`);
```

You should also avoid storing dates as text. Use `DATETIME` if you can.

Comment: Yes there are indexes on all essential criteria.

Comment: Also on the `value` field that you are sorting on?

Comment: Well not on values really. Let's say you have 12 records for 4 clients, 3 records per client for 100 euros per record, for various dates of the year. The query will return a list of 4 clients and the sum of  300 euros per client. In the actual table the list will return the values in descending order. One idea was to create another table that would hold the actual query results. In theory that would have grouped the records and the table would be smaller. But we would somehow need to retain the date values for each record. That meant that the table size would only shrink by 20%.

Comment: Is the date really stored as a string? Wouldn't it be better to store it as an actual DATETIME type to avoid all the string processing?